# Kafka read finite list from topic

Tags: apache-kafka

What would be the best way to read a finite list of related records from a kafka topic? For example, results from db query containing a few hundred records. How would I know the "end"? Simple flag in the header?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to query Kafka. In that case you may want to try KSQL (https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql ). It allows you to create SQL-like queries like SELECT * FROM mytopic WHERE regionid LIKE '%_8' OR regionid LIKE '%_9' LIMIT 100;

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not a good choice for such use cases. You have to remember start and end offsets of the messages corresponding to the DB query and also you have to ensure that those messages go to single partition, as otherwise they may get added out of orders and even more states to remember. If you use one exclusive topic for each query, that will work better. Kafka is not that a good choice for creating and deleting topics on the fly.

Instead a Redis list will be a much better choice for the use case you are mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am evaluating kafka vs rabbitmq for an upcoming  project. I looked at ksql but it says on the github sight "dev only". Seems like Nipun's suggestion might be the way to go.